# Change Symfony 2.7 database connection to mySql - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, symfony, xampp

I installed Symfony 2.7 on my Windows 7 XAMPP development machine. What is the easiest(rather best practice..) way to make it use mySql on the local machine?

My parameters.yml uses sqlite but I figured out that this is a generated file (am I correct?) and if I un-comment the correct block in parameters.yml.dist some magic command (am I right?) will re-generate parameters.yml with mysql.

Any help? I am trying to find it in the DOCS and this might yield faster result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**parameters.yml.dist** is a reference of all required parameters, so that you don't have to remember them. When you use the configuration wizard (as in @baig response) or composer, the **parameters.yml.dist** will be compared with the **parameters.yml** and it will ask you to fill any missing parameter.

This is the more or less the "magic" that you refer to.

Of course you may be a wizard yourself and magically open in an editor  the **parameters.yml** file and magically fill all the required parameters (or change them).

So far, so good.

But where you got things slightly wrong is that you **don't** have to put your actual settings in **parameters.yml.dist**; in fact, I suggest you not to.

**parameters.yml.dist** should contain defaults / dummy values, and by all means it should NOT contain passwords. This file is usually versioned, so you can see it's not a good idea. The actual settings will be only present in **parameters.yml** which is not versioned and can be different on any environment (i.e. your local machine, the dev server, the prod server).

Comment: Thanks, I get it.... dummy values in parameters.yml.dist and my actual values in parameters.yml My issue is that http://localhost:8000/config.php gives me a route not found. Where can I find a sample of what parameters.yml would look like if I edit it by hand in notepad++ ?

Comment: It would look exactly like your "parameters.yml.dist", but with actual values.

Comment: @Franceso, I got it working and I think your answer helped me the most. I went into parameters.yml.dist and copied\replaced the block for mySql to parameters.yml (removed the # comment in every line.) After that I ran php app/console doctrine:database:create --env=dev and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Symfony when you run the app 
`php app/console server:run` it tells you how you can access the application. At my end I can access the app via `http://127.0.0.1:8000` so using this URL you configure Symfony with database by accessing `config.php` so URL will look like 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/config.php`

Once on this URL its pretty straight forward, Symfony will ask you bunch of questions related to your database name, user and so on. Once done you are now connected with database and will notice the information you provided is automaticaly saved in `parameters.ym`

Comment: Thanks @Biag, I had everything the way you mentioned (I love the docs for Symfony!!) but where I get lost is when I go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/config.php" and get "No route found for GET /config.php" From what I can see it would be best practice to configure in the web UI but I cannot get to it... I can get to "http://127.0.0.1:8000"